# Emacs: Linux Kernel Style but with Allman/BSD Style Braces?

Tags: emacs, elisp

What emacs Lisp code in .emacs.el or .emacs.d/init.el would produce Linux kernel style indentation (8 spaces throughout, or am I wrong) but with Allman/BSD style braces?

Comment: This terse question without details or examples makes it hard for anyone to help you or know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs' default linux style already has that braces style, so this should suffice:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-style "linux")))
```